# How can I fill column with some data depending on data in another column? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have such table:

```
ID|value
0|1
1|0
2|1
```

And i want to do SELECT query that return me this:

```
ID|value|isOne
0|1|+ 
1|0|- 
2|1|+
```

- If value content 1, isOne is "+".
- If value content 0, isOne is "-".

I thought about nested queries or "if-else" construction but I'm not sure if it's a good solution.

Comment: What should be the task? You dont need another column isOne, you see that in value column... Why?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `case` expression:

```
select t.*, (case when value = 1 then '+' else '-' end) as flag
from t;
```

More commonly, though, you would just use a `0`/`1` flag.  But that seems to be what you are starting with.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `IF()` function:

```
SELECT ID, value, IF(value, "+", "-") AS isOne FROM table_name
```

read this for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `IF` expression, is shorter.

```
SELECT `id`, `value`, IF(`value` = 1, '+', '-') AS `sign` FROM `your_table`
```